# Help evaluating covariance integral when deriving vasiceks model

Tags: vasicek

Im working through a solution to evaluating pricing for Vasiceks model [image]

However i dont understand the u∧t terms and how that behaves under the integrals...any help??

Cheers

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more your question @user28140? It is unclear what you asking exactly.

Comment: $u\wedge t=\min(u, t)$.

Comment: go to check answer ur question p. 592 in Handbook of Multi-Commodity Markets and Products: Structuring, Trading and Risk Management by Andrea Roncoroni.

Answer (score 2):

that symbol means "the min of". So for example, if: $s<t$, then $s$ ^ t = s.

If you look in any book for the Covariance of a BM, you will see that same symbol and how to work with it. Cheers.